# Enviar múltiples archivos por correo luego de guardarlos en un servidor con PHP

Tags: php, formularios

Buen día con todos, tengo el siguiente problema: 
Diseñé un formulario de registro, este envía los datos a un archivo PHP este los guarda en una base de datos y los archivos adjuntos los carga al servidor; al finalizar agregué el "include_once('guardar_formulario_correo.php');" para enviarlos por correo y con los archivos adjuntos, pero sólo me envía uno, no todos.

```
    $encabezado = "From: $deNombre"." <".$de."> \r\n" .
                "Reply-To: $correo\r\n" .
                "Cc: $correo\r\n" .
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

// Revisar los archivos del servidor
$path = "files/".$nCarpeta;
if(file_exists($path)){
    $directorio = opendir($path);
    while ($archivo = readdir($directorio))
    {
        if (!is_dir($archivo)){
            $aduntos = array($path."/".$archivo);
        }
    }
}

$files = $aduntos;

$semi_Rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_Rand}x"; 

$encabezado .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

$mensaje = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $cuerpo . "\n\n"; 

$mensaje .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// Preparando los archivos
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $mensaje .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $mensaje .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigos, he cambiado el código del for() y ahora ya me envía los archivos que selecciono, sin embargo, al nombre le agrega la ruta completa, es decir los renombra (ej, archivo.pdf lo convierte a files100archivo.pdf, donde "files" es la carpeta que contiene a "100" files es una carpeta establecida mientras que "100" se crea con el id de registro guardado en las base de datos y dentro me guarda todos los archivos que envío), agrego el código y me gustaría que me pudieran orientar, quizá se deba cambiar gran parte del código o a lo mejor sea más simple de lo que parece.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $cuerpo =file_get_contents($files[$x],"rb");
    $cuerpo = chunk_split(base64_encode($cuerpo));
    $mensaje .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $cuerpo . "\n\n";
    $mensaje .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}
```